# how to access pointer member of nested structure in c code from another file

Tags: c

Below is complete code

brief summary of my problem is below:
I have one global structure as mentioned below in file1.c and its getting initialized with some value in file1.c by function"assign_value()"  and now I am printing  this value by function "print_value()" from file2.c.

Problem is that: its not printing proper value from file2.c on the other hand if I call "print_value()" from file1.c inside function "assign_value()" as mentioned below then it shows proper value.

Please suggest what I am missing, why I am not able to print proper value by calling print_value() function in file2.c

```
  file1.c
```

My_struct_one is nested structure containing another structure My_struct_two and my_struct_obj_global is global variable in file1.c

```
    //file1.c

    #include <stdio.h>

    #include "file1.h"

    typedef unsigned long int List;

    typedef struct
    {

     List* my_list;
    }My_struct_two;


     typedef struct
    {

     My_struct_two struct_two;
    }My_struct_one;


     My_struct_one struct_global;



      void assign_value()
     {
     List value=9;

     struct_global.struct_two.my_list = &value;
     print_value();
     }

    void print_value()
    {
    printf("inside print");
    printf("value=%u\n",*(struct_global.struct_two.my_list));
    }
```

file1.h
      //file.h

```
  #ifndef _file1_c

  #define _file1_c

  void print_value();
  void assign_value();

  #endif
```

file2.c
      #include

```
  #include "file1.h"

  int main()

  {

  assign_value();

  print_value();

  return 0;

   }
```

OUTPUT:
inside printvalue=9
inside printvalue=4195506

Mine doubt is why I cant access value from file2.c,

Comment: Start by putting common definitions and declarations in a *header file* that both source files could include.

Comment: And don't forget that all symbols you use must be declared or defined *before* you use them.

Comment: Lastly, listen to your compiler and what it tells you. `List* value=9;` is wrong. So is `my_struct_obj_global.my_struct_obj.my_list = &value`. It seems you either learning C by guessing (which will not work much longer) or you skipped a few chapters in whatever book your reading (or possibly skipped a few classes). My recommendation is that you get a couple of books and start over. Good books will also describe how to split programs into multiple source and header files.

Comment: Do you link object files (file1.o and file2.o) together or do you have an include statement in file2.c (do you include a header file or the c file)? Because, in one case it might work, in others it will not.

Comment: @kmartin: yes I linked them below is command
gcc -c file1.c
gcc -c file2.c
gcc -o my_bin file1.o file2.o

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude:  to save time I directly wrote code here, for sake I uploaded complete compiled code and output, you are deviating from my main question, my question was how can I access value in above case from another file

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `value` is a local variable in function `assign_value()`. It is created when the function is entered, and it is destroyed when the function returns.
- In function `print_value()`, the value of `struct_global.struct_two.my_list` is a dangling pointer: its value is the address of a variable which does not exist any more.
- Dereferencing the value of a dangling pointer is undefined behavior.